# jquery has in if statement triggering in any case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm using jquery `.has()` to check if a `div` has an `ul` inside it. it's in a `if` statement but it fires in any case, even if the `div` doesn't have the `ul` inside it:

```js
if ($(".cs-error").has("ul")) {
  alert("it has a UL")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cs-error">

</div>
```

what am i missing? I didn't try much because well.. I'm supposed to do this simple thing and I couldn't find a better way to do it. I already use .has() in other circumstances and it always worked

Comment: *"what am i missing"* ... certainly missed posting your code in the question. We shouldn't have to go off site just to review your initial problem

Comment: i find it more practical to have a working use case instead of copy pasting 2 lines of code @charlietfl

Comment: What's more convenient for you is not relevant. Questions should be self contained and you should be considering convenience and value to readers. Those are site guidelines

Comment: @valerio0999 Then create a snippet via the snippet editor. Questions that don’t themselves contain the reproducible code are off-topic.

Comment: @valerio0999 Pro-tip, do both; JSFiddles are not permanent. Show code here and provide JSFiddle if you want brownie-points with the lads of StackOverflow. Since you are the one having an issue, make it easy for anyone willing to help. And don't forget Code Snippets.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus i always do, stackoverflow stops you if the question is too "dry".. it accepted it as i wrote it so i figured it was enough. sorry

Comment: I didn't downvote but just wanted to give you some guidelines for the future. I personally prefer Fiddles especially when actively working on something through the comments section to easily go back and forth showing Fiddle revisions.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Why your want to increase count of your *edited post*  by your wrong edit?

Comment: @Mohammad, my aim is not to "increase the count of my edited posts". I rolled back your edits because the first one modified code in the question (replacing `alert()` with `console.log()`), which is both superfluous and frowned upon. As for the second one, the proper casing of the library's name is *jQuery*, not *Jquery*.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Your reason doesn't confirm rolling back. `console` is better than `alert()` for question/answer as another stack snippet. You said *the library's name is jQuery* but you doesn't use it.

Comment: @Mohammad, I didn't fix the casing in the title because, honestly, such a trivial edit doesn't bring anything to the table. `console.log()` *may* be "better" than `alert()` (at least in your opinion, and mine), but edits are not meant for us to force our personal preferences down the throats of the other users. The questioner originally used `alert()`, let them be.

Comment: @Mohammad: In addition to the preference thing, sometimes `alert` vs. `console.log` actually matters to what happens. In general, best to edit other people's code on-site with a light touch, if at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(".cs-error").has("ul")` will give you a `jQuery` object nonetheless - but an empty one.

So you should check if there was at least one element found:

```
if ($(".cs-error").has("ul").length) {
```

Comment: `if($('.cs-error ul').length)` is one less function call.

Comment: thanks! i'm accepting this one in..10 minutes :) thanks a lot